# Is it a bad idea to implement an RSS feed for help desk assignments?

Tags: rss

Before I ask my question, let me just say that I know very little about RSS feeds. I tried using Google Reader a long time ago, but I just don't think RSS is my thing. Now, onto the question.

The company I work for uses a custom web-based help desk system. I have been asked to implement RSS feeds into it. Specifically, I have been asked to create an RSS feed for each support agent's tickets. This way, support agents that use RSS readers can be notified whenever a ticket gets assigned to them. The thing is I don't know if this is something that RSS would be good for. Tickets get reassigned frequently. So let's say that John Doe and Jane Doe both subscribe to their respective RSS feeds to be notified whenever a ticket gets assigned to them. A ticket gets assigned to John Doe. 30 minutes later, the manager changes his mind and reassigns the ticket to Jane Doe. How would this look in John Doe's RSS reader? Would there be a way to remove it from his feed or what?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use RSS as a notification system.  When you do look at it completely from this perspective, it isn't a terrible idea.  At worst, the support person would get notified of a new ticket and log in to be pleasantly surprised that the ticket is no longer there.

If you look at something like JIRA, it uses email notification to inform people that tickets have been assigned.  If a ticket gets reassigned, the person it was assigned to and the person that it will be assigned to are both notified of the change.  People have the option to "listen" to tickets and will get notified of any work done, status change, etc that happens on the ticket.

You might want to consider doing something like this.  Maintaining lots and lots of RSS feeds might get quite cumbersome.  What happens if a support person leaves?  With email you could simply redirect the email to another person.

As far as deleting a message, I'm pretty sure that once it is sent to the client, it is there for good.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are generally available to public without restrictions (if they know the URL). You may decide to use .htaccess and provide clients with login credentials.

It would look just fine in John's Doe RSS reader after he refreshes it.